# Java compareAndSet to atomically update references in a BST

Tags: java, c, binary-search-tree, java.util.concurrent, compare-and-swap

In a binary tree, I'm trying to atomically replace left child of parent to a new node.
In the below method, `pnode.left` is pointing to `node` and I'm trying to change it
to `replaceNode`.

In line1, `childPtr` is pointing to `pnode.left`
In line2, `oldChildPtr` is pointing to `pnode.left`
In line3, `childPtr` is atomically changed from pointing to`pnode.left` to `replaceNode`.

But `pnode.left` is unchanged. I understand that this is how things work in java.
But how do I modify this code so that `pnode.left` is atomically replaced with `replaceNode`.

```
atomicReplaceLeftChild(node,pnode,replaceNode)
{
    AtomicReference<Node> childPtr = new AtomicReference<Node>(pnode.left);
    Node oldChildPtr = childPtr.get();
    childPtr.compareAndSet(oldChildPtr, replaceNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question (aand the fact that it is tagged with both `java` and `c`) suggests you are coming from a C background. Nothing wrong with this, but I believe your concept of 'atomic' in a Java sense is not what you think it is. The `Atomic*` classes in `java.util.concurrent` package use internal locking mechanisms to ensure that the values in them cannot be partially completed before another thread gets access to them. Just because you use an `Atomic*` class in your code does not mean that your code does an atomic operation.

Your three lines of code are 'odd' and do not appear to represent a real use case. I say this because the code does not **do** anything. It creates an AtomicReference instance, and it messes with the referenced value, but it does nothing to change anything on `pnode` which is what I thought you were trying to do....

So, at some point you need to have `pnode.left = replaceNode`. It is possible that you may want pnode.left to actually be an AtomicReference itself, in which case it would be: `pnode.left.compareAndSet(oldChildPtr, replaceNode)`

In it's current state your code does not do much of any significance, and certainly does not do what you describe it should do.

Hope this does not discourage you.... assuming you are new to Java I don't envy you having to start off on Atomics and concurrency.... there are easier places to start.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand my code is not doing anything. That is why in my question I said "But pnode.left is unchanged". I can do what you suggested. `pnode.left.compareAndSet(oldChildPtr, replaceNode)`. But then `pnode.left`has to be of type `AtomicReference<Node>` instead of `Node`

Answer (score 0):

```
static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> c0Update = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "c0");
static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> c1Update = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "c1");
static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> c2Update = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "c2");
static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, Node> c3Update = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, Node.class, "c3");
static final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<Node, UpdateStep> infoUpdate = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Node.class, UpdateStep.class, "pending");
```

I do a CAS by using

```
c0Update.compareAndSet(pending.p, pending.l, pending.newChild)
```

I there a easy way to do it other than manually unrolling the array elements?